# How to use variable in commanda expecting database, table, user name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need to create some stored procedures that receive as parameter db name, table name, user name, etc and do some processing on them.
I can create them using dynamic sql, but I'd like to know if it's possible to use variable name in commands that expects db name or table name.

E.g. instead of

```
USE [MyDataBase]
CREATE LOGIN [MyUser] WITH PASSWORD=N'MyPass', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[MyDataBase]
```

to be able to have

```
DECLARE @MyDB nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @MyUser nvarchar(100)

-- .... set @MyUser here

Select @MyDB = DB_NAME()
USE @MyDB
CREATE LOGIN @MyUser WITH PASSWORD=@MyPass, DEFAULT_DATABASE= @DbName
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These can't be parameterised unfortunately.

You need to use dynamic SQL.

See [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL - Dealing with Dynamic Table and Column Names](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#objectnames) for some advice on how to do this as safely as possible.